# Multiple FB.Event.subscribe won't fire but single does

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to add `comment.create` and `comment.remove` to a page

If i use the following, all is ok:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function(){ 
    FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function(response){
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST", // form method
    url: "/pages/includes/add_fb_comments.php",// destination
    data: "url=" + encodeURIComponent(response.href) + "&id=<?=$id?>&action=add",
    cache: false,
    success: function(){
    alert('Success' + encodeURIComponent(response.href) + response.commentID);
    }
    });
    });
    };
```

but, however and wherever I add the following, nothing fires, the ajax doesn't fire and thus no success message

```
FB.Event.subscribe('comment.remove', function(response){
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST", // form method
    url: "/pages/includes/add_fb_comments.php",// destination
    data: "commentID=" + response.commentID + "&action=remove",
    cache: false,
    success: function(){
    alert('removed comment: ' response.commentID);
    }
    });
});
```

I've tried both within the same `window.fbAsyncInit = function(){` I've tried seperate `window.fbAsyncInit = function(){` I've even tried complete seperate `<script></script>` but they simply don't fire.

Is this a known problem? I can't believe it is as surely these always exist together

Any ideas?

This is the full actual code i'm trying:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="<? echo curPageURL(); ?>" data-num-posts="4" data-width="578" mobile="false"></div>
        <script>
            window.fbAsyncInit = function(){ 
                    FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function(response){
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST", // form method
                            url: "/pages/includes/add_fb_comments.php",// destination
                            data: "url=" + encodeURIComponent(response.href) + "&id=<?=$id?>&action=add",
                            cache: false,
                            success: function(){
                            alert('Success' + encodeURIComponent(response.href) + response.commentID);
                            }
                        });
                    });
            };

            window.fbAsyncInit = function(){ 
                    FB.Event.subscribe('comment.remove', function(response){
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST", // form method
                            url: "/pages/includes/add_fb_comments.php",// destination
                            data: "commentID=" + response.commentID + "&action=remove",
                            cache: false,
                            success: function(){
                            alert('removed comment: ' response.commentID);
                            }
                        });
                    });
            };
            </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Each `window.fbAsyncInit` is setting the same property, and as these are executed sequentially, and are not cumulative, only the last function is actually set.

Now, I'm pretty sure you also have a third `fbAsyncInit =...` block, where the SDK is initialized and all, and due to the above this never executes.

Move all of this into a single `fbAsyncInit` and you should be good.